# In an OS X swift application we want to link custom class to a custom view programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

We are linking custom class to a custom view like this.[image]

But in our last application we are creating custom views programmatically, so we need to link custom classes to those custom views programmatically as well.

We could not find a way till now.

Comment: You don't need to attach anything. If you have the class view you just instantiate that from code.

Comment: But as I tried to explain we are creating views programmatically and there is nothing like "class view"? but there is a class we wanted that class to work with those views. When views added by using Xcode's Scene editor class could be added to views like in the image at question.

Comment: For example I have a view (created from code) named `MyCustomView` subclassing `UIView`. If you want to add it into the storyboard, you'll have to drag a `UIView` into the storyboard and set it's custom class to `MyCostomView`. If you want the view to be shown into the storyboard you'll have to use `IBInspectable` and `INDesignable` (http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/). Is this answering your question?

Comment: "set it's custom class to MyCostomView" this is the point, how can you set it programmatically.

Comment: How do you create the view programmatically?

Comment: @Hope you just set it to the `UIView` you dragged into the storyboard, like you showed in the picture above.

Comment: `anNSView.className`  returns class name of that view. But I need something like _anNSView.className = NewClassName_  but _className_ is read only unfortunately

Comment: @Willeke, at ViewController class, We are creating NSViews like this `childViews.append( NSView (frame : CGRectMake (x, y, w, h)))  ; parentView.addSubview(childViews[index]);`

Comment: Change this to `childViews.append( DrawImageHolder (frame : CGRectMake (x, y, w, h))) ; parentView.addSubview(childViews[index]);`

Answer (score 0):

Before you use a view, you need to instantiate it. Instead of instantiating an NSView (you cannot change the class later), you need to instantiate a MyView.

That's the short answer. The longer answer is that you probably need to slow down with development and read up more on basic application architecture, because your question shows that you are not very familiar with the principles, and this will come to bite you many, many times. For starters, I will also recommend that - unless you're working in SpriteKit - you use Autolayout in your application, and give your view an intrinsic size rather setting the frame directly.